# Depth estimation with estereo vision

Tags: python, opencv

I have a pretty good idea on how to make a depth estimation of an object in Python, but I have some problens on how to calculate the focal length and de FOV of cameras. Furthermore, what is the best way to calculate the depth?

I'm trying to use the equation

```
Z = (baseline*f_pixel)/disp
```

Is this the best way of doing it? If it is, should I calculate a Z to each camera? And if each camera has a different focal lenght, should I use a f_pixel for each camera?